# Dereferenced pointer changes address in function call

Tags: c, pointers, embedded, atmelstudio

I have a struct declared and set in memory, I have a global constant pointer to this struct and throughout my program I dereference this pointer to access the different parts of the struct. However, there are times when the pointer memory address changes when dereferenced from a specific function.

My struct

```
typedef struct configData_t
{
    uint8_t version[4];
    inputConfig_t  inputModuleConfig  [MAX_INPUT];
    outputConfig_t outputModuleConfig [MAX_OUTPUT];
    notificationConfig_t notificationConfig [MAX_NOTIFICATIONS];
    functionConfig_t autoFunctionConfig [MAX_FUNCTIONS];
    uint16_t Crc16;
} configData_t;
```

The constant pointer is declared by setting the memory address of the data (externally loaded and outside of the applications memory)

```
//Pointer points to memory location on uC (data already in memory)
const configData_t* theConfigData = (configData_t*)0x0460000;
```

To get a notification from the 'notificationConfig' array I dereference 'theConfigData' by [1]:

```
const notificationConfig_t *pNotificationConfig = theConfigData->notificationConfig + notificationID;
```

The following occurs when stepping through the code on the uC:

1. In function A, get notification from struct by using [1], pointer address is 0x463e18
2. In function A call function B, dereference the struct using [1] the address changes to 0x463e2a (This is the wrong memory address, 0x12 difference)
3. Function B finishes and returns to A, dereferencing theConfigData again using [1] gives 0x463e18
4. Every other function in the program that uses [1] always returns the correct (0x463e18) address.

Function B does not alter 'theConfigData' in any way. In the debuggers memory view, the data in 0x0460000 + sizeOf(configData_t) is not altered in any way.

How is the 'pNotificationConfig' pointer changing address when going from function A to B?

Comment: Is function B in the same compilation unit as function A? (else, there could be allignment issues)

Comment: Without relevant code from functions A and B, it is only possible to guess.   Odds are some code, somewhere, is molesting a pointer (e.g. dereferencing a NULL, going past the end of an array, doing something with wrong alignment).   The offending code could be anywhere - in one of the functions you mention, or somewhere else.    Without a [mcve] you can't expect anyone to offer specific answers though.    The fact you are initialising a pointer to a fixed value, and later dereferencing it, is also a possible cause of problems.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie function B is in a separate compilation unit.

Comment: are you sure `notificationID` isn't different in function B ?

Comment: Most likely a bug either in in that function or in the calling code. Other alternatives are classic stack overflow, or perhaps strict aliasing bugs if gcc is involved.

Comment: @Peter Function I have reduced function A and function B down to just the code in [1] and I still have the same issue.

Comment: or alternatively that `sizeof(notificationConfig_t)` is different in function B ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Yes, I have tried with a fixed value and not using 'notificationID' at all

Comment: or alternatively that `offsetof(configData_t, notificationConfig)` is different in function B ?

Comment: @AaronThompson - as I said, the possibilities are endless. One possibility is that some other function (executed before functions A and B) has screwed something up (e.g. overwritten `pNotificationConfig` due to falling off the end of an unrelated array).  One "feature" of undefined behaviour is that the code where a symptom occurs (your functions A and B)  is not necessarily the code that causes the problem.   Repeatedly telling us where the SYMPTOM occurs therefore tells us NOTHING about the cause.   A I said, a [mcve] is needed if you expect help that doesn't rely on guess work.

Comment: Quote " get notification from struct by using [1]" Well, I don't see any code using `[1]`

Comment: Are there any interrupts enabled on the uC ? Is your struct declared as `static` ?

Comment: Most likely in my opinion is an allignment issue in the compilation of modules with function A and function B. Check the compiler flags and packing pragmas. Suggestions of stack overflow or overwriting the pointer as suggested by others is wrong because after function B returns, all other functions use the correct address, as you say.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker the sizeOf(configData_t) is different in function A and function B, would this indicate an alignment issue?

Comment: @AaronThompson : it could be a padding issue. It could be an issue with different definitions of `configData_t`. As a first suspect, I would check whether either `MAX_INPUT` and/or `MAX_OUTPUT` are different in the B compilation unit (at the point of he `configData_t` definition). If they're the same, check whether the `configData_t` definition differs in another way. If there's no difference, then check compiler flags (specifically wrt. struct packing).

Comment: Thank you @SanderDeDycker and @PaulOgilvie, it was an alignment issue between the different compilation units. Adding `__attribute__((__packed__))` to the `typedef struct` has solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that :

- the definition of `configData_t` is exactly the same in both the function A and function B compilation units
- the [struct padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-packing) of `configData_t` is exactly the same for both the function A and function B compilation units

Red flags of the above for your specific issue would be eg. :

- `sizeof(configData_t)` is different
- `offsetof(configData_t, notificationConfig)` is different
- `sizeof(notificationConfig_t)` is different

If one or more of these red flags are raised (and in a comment, you confirm that), you need to determine which of the two earlier options causes it :

- a difference in definition can be caught by verifying the source code :

  - make sure the same struct definitions are used throughout the code (typically with the use of an include file)
  - make sure supporting compile time values are the same (eg. array dimensions `MAX_INPUT`, `MAX_OUTPUT`, ... in your case)
- a difference in padding can be caused by the use of different compilers and/or different compiler flags - refer to your compiler's documentation for details (specifically wrt. struct padding/packing)